# Order of JSON returned by ORMLite?

Tags: sql, oracle, ormlite

I'm new to web services and trying to query some tables using ORMLite, it doesn't support join statements so I'm using a raw query. I was wondering if there is a way to specify how the JSON is returned. What I have right now is:

```
Dao<CodesModel,String> CodesDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, CodesModel.class);

    GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
      CodesDao.queryRaw(
        "select r.CodeA, s.SubCodeA, r.CodeB, s.SubCodeB " + 
        "from CodesTable r JOIN SubCodesTable s ON s.CodeA = r.CodeA " + 
        "where SubCodeB = '" + b_sub + "' AND r.CodeB = '" + b_code + "'");
```

And the results are returned as a String[] and always seem to be in the order of

[CodeA, SubCodeA, CodeB, SubCodeB]

but I have only tested this locally and can't find in the documentation what determines the order for variables in the array that is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are ordered that way because that is the order in which you specified them in the select statement. If you want the results ordered in a different way, reorder them in your query.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't 100% sure it worked that way. I ended up using a select all and just joining on those columns so I'll also post my code for that to help others

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a way to know column names when using "select *" you can also use "getColumnNames()" on the rawResults object and they will always be in the order that the results are. Examples

```
    //The result is returned as a GenericRawResults object
    List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();
    String[] columns = rawResults.getColumnNames();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    if(results.size()>0)
    {
        obj.put(columns[0], results.get(0)[0]);
        obj.put(columns[1], results.get(0)[1]);
        obj.put(columns[2], results.get(0)[2]);
        obj.put(columns[3], results.get(0)[3]);
    }
```